Grouped in alphabetical order
The task is to break the string of letters (somehow) and place the correct letters in the list (1-5) below and ofc explain why it's correct.
  DWETFRHTMNNSST 

1. 
2. 
3.
4. 
5. 


I think the letters that are supposed to be listed beside the numbers are...

 ...the 5 English vowels: A, E, I, O, and U. I have chosen to list them in alphabetical order as per the title, although that's not the only need for alphabetical order in this puzzle...

First, split the string into...

 seven consecutive pairs of letters:

 DW ET FR HT MN NS ST

 Note that these seven entries are themselves arranged in alphabetical order (D... E... F... H... M... N... S...).

Now recognise that each of these is...

 a 3-day abbreviation for a day of a week missing a letter, with the remaining 2 letters arranged in alphabetical order:

 W(e)D T(u)E FR(i) TH(u) M(o)N S(u)N S(a)T

 Of particular note here is that these missing letters are all vowels, and what's more all five of the common English vowels are represented here (A, E, I, O and U 3 times). Thus, these should be the missing letters that help us create our list.

How did I break into this in the first place?

 When looking at the letters in the string, I happened to notice that all the letters that start the days of the week were present (M, T, W, T, F, S, and S). What's more, the W was close to a D (both present in 'Wednesday'), the F was beside an R (both in 'Friday') and when split into pairs the rest held a similar relationship. The reasoning followed from there.

EDIT: One clarification provided by the OP in comments:

 Although the wording was a tad ambiguous, rather than just listing the vowels as the 'letters' needed for the 5 numbered points, the OP had hoped for the final answer to look as follows, using the 'letters' from the original string:

 1. ST
 2. DW
 3. FR
 4. MN
 5. ET, HT, NS

 This way the 'disemvowelled' (and alphabetised) substrings appear beside the number corresponding to the vowel that is missing (A=1, E=2, I=3, O=4, U=5 in alphabet order). Either way the sentiment is the same, just the presentation is different.


Well done! I realized I worded it bit poorly, the idea was to place the letters of the string in that list. ST on 1st (vowel) position, DW on 2nd (vowel) position etc..

For the last one (5) three of them would just be placed in alphabetical order. Nonetheless, your answer works too ofc

@Prim3numbah Aha, okay, I see. Yes, there were a lot of 'letters' flying around in that opening description...
